# Knowing what New() constructor is used

Tags: vb.net, constructor

I'm making a class that can "send" data from `List(Of String)` or from `ListBox.ObjectCollection`. How can I know if what constructor is used? This is my code (I can do it in my code but it maybe the crude way).

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class ExtendedFileSender
    Public LstFileList As List(Of String)
    Public LvwFileList As ListBox.ObjectCollection
    Public ExTcpClient As ExtendedTcpClient
    Private ReadOnly _boolIsList As Boolean

    Public Sub New(client As ExtendedTcpClient, data As List(Of String))
        ExTcpClient = client
        LstFileList = data
        _boolIsList = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(client As ExtendedTcpClient, data As ListBox.ObjectCollection)
        ExTcpClient = client
        LvwFileList = data
        _boolIsList = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartSend()
        If _boolIsList = True Then
            Dim senderThread = New Thread(AddressOf SendFileFromList)
            senderThread.Start(LstFileList)
        Else
            Dim senderThread = New Thread(AddressOf SendFileFromListView)
            senderThread.Start(LvwFileList)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendFileFromList(fileList As List(Of String))
        For Each strFile In fileList
            Debug.WriteLine(strFile)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendFileFromListView(fileList As ListBox.ObjectCollection)
        For Each strFile In fileList
            Debug.WriteLine(strFile)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am assuming that you want to know which constructor was used so that you know which collection property to use?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to know which constructor was used, except setting a flag like you are.  I suppose you could use `If LstFileList IsNot Nothing Then` instead of the `_boolIsList` flag.  However, if you are assuming that `fileList` always contains strings, could you just have one constructor that takes `IEnumerable(Of String)` or something similar that is less specific about the type of collection?

Comment: Of course, this is always a bad idea to design objects in such way. This breaks single responsibility principle. You better create a class that does some action on `List<T>` and then create some extension methods on your `ListView` and `ListBox`. Then then just call `lstBox.MySendExtension()`anf `lstview.MySendExtension()`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done VB in many years but you would simply check which field was not populated. I recommend that you throw an ArgumentNullException in your constructor if your parameters are set to Nothing. Otherwise your class may not operate as you intend.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class ExtendedFileSender
    Public LstFileList As List(Of String)
    Public LvwFileList As ListBox.ObjectCollection
    Public ExTcpClient As ExtendedTcpClient

    Public Sub New(client As ExtendedTcpClient, data As List(Of String))
        ExTcpClient = client
        LstFileList = data
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(client As ExtendedTcpClient, data As ListBox.ObjectCollection)
        ExTcpClient = client
        LvwFileList = data
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartSend()
        If LstFileList IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim senderThread = New Thread(AddressOf SendFileFromList)
            senderThread.Start(LstFileList)
        Else
            Dim senderThread = New Thread(AddressOf SendFileFromListView)
            senderThread.Start(LvwFileList)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendFileFromList(fileList As List(Of String))
        For Each strFile In fileList
            Debug.WriteLine(strFile)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendFileFromListView(fileList As ListBox.ObjectCollection)
        For Each strFile In fileList
            Debug.WriteLine(strFile)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Taking into account your comment _I haven't done VB in many years_ (so this isn't a criticism). Think instead of <> it would be IsNot. <> would be to compare String, Integer, Boolean etc whilst IsNot would be to compare classes such as List(Of T).

Comment: I had a vague memory that there was another operator to use.